# Javascript to detect google toolbar in IE9 64 bit

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, 64-bit

Looking for a way to detect, in IE, the presence of Google toolbar, i've noticed that in 64bit environment, and using IE9, http_user_agent doesn't show the information about it.

For example, in IE8

> `Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; BTRS31753;`**`GTB7.4`**`)`

but not in IE9

Any idea?

Comment: I need to notify to user if GT is installed, just becouse it could interfer with other apps that users use

Answer (score 4):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Google Toolbar Detection</title>
        <object id="detection" classid="clsid:00EF2092-6AC5-47c0-BD25-CF2D5D657FEB"></object>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            if (typeof (detection) != "undefined") {
                if (typeof (detection.Search) != "undefined") {
                    document.write("Google Toolbar Installed");
                } else {
                    document.write("Google Toolbar Not Installed");
                }
            } else {
                document.write("This is not MSIE");
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems that it doesn't work. It write: Google Toolbar Not Installed